# How to control highlighted cell with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML table

When I click on it's cell (not header) this cell is highlighted in red. the rest cells in the same row are highlighted in pink color.

I want to control this red cell using arrow keys.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table Highlight</title>
    </head>

    <style>
        .highlighted{
            color: white;
            background-color: red;
        }

        tr.normal td {
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .highlighted1 {
            color: white;
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>

    <body onLoad="onLoad()" >
        <table id="tbl" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:70">Id
                <td style="width:70">Name
                <td style="width:70">Year
                <td style="width:70">Task
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20"> 
                <td style="height:20"> 
                <td style="height:20"> 
                <td style="height:20"> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20">
                <td style="height:20">
                <td style="height:20">
                <td style="height:20">
            </tr>
            <tr>            
                <td style="height:20">
                <td style="height:20">
                <td style="height:20">
                <td style="height:20">
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
            tbl2 = document.getElementById('tbl');
            cnt = 0;
            function onLoad() {
                td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
                for(j=4;j<td.length;j++){
                    td[j].innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    td[j].onclick = function(){highlight(this)}
                    td[j].onkeydown=function(){key_highlight(event)}
                }
            }

            function key_highlight(oo) {
                td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

                for(n=1;i<tbl2.rows;n++){
                    cnt=0;
                    /*
                    if(cnt > tbl2[i].cells.length) return;
                        highlight(tbl2[i]);
                    }*/
                    alert();

                    //if(oo.keyCode==39)
                    if(cnt>tbl2.rows[n].cells.length) return;
                    highlight(tbl2[n].cells);
                    cnt++;
                }
            }

            function highlight(o) {
                for (i=0; i<tbl.cells.length; i++){
                    tbl.cells[i].className="normal";
                    tbl.cells[i].parentNode.className="normal";
                }
                o.parentNode.className = (o.className == "highlighted1")?"normal":"highlighted1";;
                o.className=(o.className == "highlighted")?"normal":"highlighted";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `keycode` on `keydown` event for the document and apply `"highlighted" class` to respective `td`.

**HTML :**

```
<table id="tbl" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:70" class="highlighted">Id</td>
            <td style="width:70">Name</td>
            <td style="width:70">Year</td>
            <td style="width:70">Task</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:20"> 1</td>
            <td style="height:20"> Bob</td>
            <td style="height:20"> 1998</td>
            <td style="height:20"> NA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:20">2</td>
            <td style="height:20">Maz</td>
            <td style="height:20">2000</td>
            <td style="height:20">QA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td style="height:20">3</td>
            <td style="height:20">Mary</td>
            <td style="height:20">1999</td>
            <td style="height:20">Code</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
var active;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    active = $('td.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    var x = active.index();
    var y = active.closest('tr').index();
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       x--;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        y--;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
        x++
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        y++
    }
    active = $('tr').eq(y).find('td').eq(x).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

Refer to **[fiddle for live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/8fu9u4x7/)**

Comment: @user152251, are you fine with the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of cell position (cellX,cellY) both when you click and when you press a key. Add a global keypress handler (document.onkeydown = ) and increment or decrement cellX and cellY according to the keys pressed.

Chech the running fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aehq9c6f/1/

```
        tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
        tbl2 = document.getElementById('tbl');

        var cellX=null;
        var cellY=null;

        document.onkeydown = keyPressed;

        cnt = 0;
        function onLoad() {
            td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
            for(j=4;j<td.length;j++){
                td[j].innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                td[j].onclick = function(){highlight(this)}
                td[j].onkeydown=function(){key_highlight(event)}
            }
        }
        function keyPressed(e) {
            var code;
            if (!e) var e = window.event;
            if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
            else if (e.which) code = e.which;

            var KeyVal=getCharDesc(code);


            var maxX=4;
            var maxY=4;

            if(KeyVal=="left") {
                if(cellX===null) cellX=maxX;
                if(cellY===null) cellY=maxY/2;
                cellX--;
                if(cellX<0) cellX=maxX-1;
                highlight(tbl.rows[cellY].cells[cellX]);
            } else if(KeyVal=="right") {
                if(cellX===null) cellX=-1;
                if(cellY===null) cellY=maxY/2;
                cellX++;
                if(cellX>maxX-1) cellX=0;
                highlight(tbl.rows[cellY].cells[cellX]);
            } else if(KeyVal=="up") {
                if(cellX===null) cellX=maxX/2;
                if(cellY===null) cellY=maxY;
                cellY--;
                if(cellY<1) cellY=maxY-1;  // avoid top row
                highlight(tbl.rows[cellY].cells[cellX]);
            } else if(KeyVal=="down") {
                if(cellX===null) cellX=maxX/2;
                if(cellY===null) cellY=0; // avoid top row
                cellY++;
                if(cellY>maxY-1) cellY=1; // avoid top row
                highlight(tbl.rows[cellY].cells[cellX]);
            }


         }
        function getCharDesc(char_code) {
            switch(char_code) {
                case 37:return "left"; 
                case 38:return "up"; 
                case 39:return "right"; 
                case 40:return "down"; 
            }
        }

        function highlight(o) {
            for (var i = 0, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    row.cells[j].className="normal";
                    row.cells[j].parentNode.className="normal";
                    if(row.cells[j]===o) {
                        cellX=j;
                        cellY=i;
                        // alert(cellX+", "+cellY);
                    }
                }
            }
            o.parentNode.className = (o.className == "highlighted1")?"normal":"highlighted1";;
            o.className=(o.className == "highlighted")?"normal":"highlighted";
        }
```

The extra tests like

if(cellX===null) ...

are to allow first keypress if nothing is selected (cellX and cellY are null), if you hit left, cursor will start from right, etc.. (window must have focus so first click window to test).

I changed tbl.cells[i] to tbl.rows[i].cells[j] because on my setup (Firefox) table.cells[..] was not defined